# Using Facebook's Post to Wall SDK, works successfully, how do I show it in a normal window, not a maximized one?

Tags: facebook, blogs, share

I have successfully implemented the Post to Wall SDK from Facebook onto my blog. http://www.adamscarter.co.uk/blog/
It works great! but the only problem is when I use the Facebook button, it forces the window to be maximized.

The size I want to make it is the size of the window, once you click the 'restore down' button in the window itself - the button betweem minimize and close - I assumed it was the property 'display' with the value 'popup'.

Does anyone know how to do this? Even, if it can be done?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=123050457758183&
display=popup&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/
```

That way, the dialogue box will open in a 400px by 580px on-page popup window.